# Highchart single point of data is not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have set marker but it's not displaying when there is only single data available.
When we hover on chart then data point is displaying.

see sample fiddle here - [jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/dc7P4B)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c4M6D/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, modify your `plotOptions` setting as follow:

```
plotOptions: {
              area: {
                marker: {
                  radius: 4,
                  lineColor: '#666666',
                  lineWidth: 0.5,
                  enabled: true
                }
              }
            },
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c4M6D/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is to dense for the markers to be drawn. See the API reference for series.marker.enabled:

[http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.marker](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Carea%3E.marker)

I updated you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4M6D/6/) with a working example. I just added one line:

```
...
"marker": {
    "enabled": "true",
    "symbol": "circle"
},
...
```